# JavaFX ListView being covered by TextArea using GridPane

Tags: java, javafx

I am working on a little game with a GUI, I am having a problem with the layout.

When I run it I get this:

[image]

The `ListView` is being covered by the `TextArea`, I am trying to get it next to it. Like in this example:

[image: Image2]

Here is the code I have so far:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.VPos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class test extends Application {

    Stage window;
    ListView<String> listView;
    TextArea descArea = new TextArea();
    TextArea actionDescArea = new TextArea();
    Label healthLabel = new Label("Health:");
    Label manaLabel = new Label("Mana:");
    Label healthDisplay = new Label("100/100");
    Label manaDisplay = new Label("100/100");
    Button actionBtn = new Button("Action");

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        window = primaryStage;
        window.setTitle("Game");

        GridPane grid = new GridPane();
        grid.setPadding(new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10));
        grid.setVgap(10);
        grid.setHgap(10);

        descArea.setPrefWidth(750);
        descArea.setPrefHeight(550);
        descArea.setWrapText(true);
        descArea.setEditable(false);
        GridPane.setConstraints(descArea, 0, 0, 1, 2);

        GridPane.setConstraints(healthLabel, 1, 0);
        GridPane.setValignment(healthLabel, VPos.TOP);

        GridPane.setConstraints(healthDisplay, 2, 0);
        GridPane.setValignment(healthDisplay, VPos.TOP);

        GridPane.setConstraints(manaLabel, 1, 1);
        GridPane.setValignment(manaLabel, VPos.TOP);

        GridPane.setConstraints(manaDisplay, 2, 1);
        GridPane.setValignment(manaDisplay, VPos.TOP);

        listView = new ListView<>();
        listView.getItems().addAll("Action 1", "Action 2", "Action 3", "Action 4");
        listView.setPrefWidth(260);
        listView.setMaxWidth(260);
        listView.setPrefHeight(150);
        GridPane.setConstraints(listView, 0, 2, 1, 1);

        actionDescArea.setPrefWidth(100);
        actionDescArea.setPrefHeight(150);
        actionDescArea.setMaxWidth(100);
        actionDescArea.setWrapText(true);
        actionDescArea.setEditable(false);
        GridPane.setConstraints(actionDescArea, 0, 2, 2, 1);

        actionBtn.setPrefWidth(260);
        actionBtn.setPrefHeight(60);
        GridPane.setConstraints(actionBtn, 0, 3);

        grid.getChildren().addAll(descArea, healthLabel, healthDisplay, manaLabel, manaDisplay, listView, actionBtn, actionDescArea);

        Scene scene = new Scene(grid, 950, 750);
        window.setScene(scene);
        window.show();
    }
```

If anyone could point me in the right direction, that would be great!

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few things to take note of :

```
GridPane.setConstraints(descArea, 0, 0, 1, 2);
```

Here, the TextArea `descArea` has a colspan is 1 with columnIndex as 0.

```
GridPane.setConstraints(listView, 0, 2, 1, 1);
```

Here, the ListView `listView` has a colspan is 1 with columnIndex as 0.

```
GridPane.setConstraints(actionDescArea, 0, 2, 2, 1);
```

Here, the TextArea `actionDescArea` has a colspan is 2 with columnIndex as 0.

If we want to place `actionDescArea` next to `listView`, it should have a columnIndex greater than that of the latter. Additionally, if we want it to grow and cover the entire width below the `descArea`, we need to set Hgrow as `Priority.Always` and remove `maxWidth`

```
GridPane.setConstraints(actionDescArea, 1, 2, 1, 1);
GridPane.setHgrow(actionDescArea, Priority.ALWAYS);
```

Additionally, since both `listView` and `actionDescArea` should be under `descArea`, its colspan should be 2.

```
GridPane.setConstraints(descArea, 0, 0, 2, 2);
```

**Solution :**

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.VPos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Test extends Application {

    Stage window;
    ListView<String> listView;
    TextArea descArea = new TextArea();
    TextArea actionDescArea = new TextArea();
    Label healthLabel = new Label("Health:");
    Label manaLabel = new Label("Mana:");
    Label healthDisplay = new Label("100/100");
    Label manaDisplay = new Label("100/100");
    Button actionBtn = new Button("Action");

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        window = primaryStage;
        window.setTitle("Game");

        GridPane grid = new GridPane();
        grid.setPadding(new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10));
        grid.setVgap(10);
        grid.setHgap(10);

        descArea.setPrefWidth(750);
        descArea.setPrefHeight(550);
        descArea.setWrapText(true);
        descArea.setEditable(false);
        GridPane.setConstraints(descArea, 0, 0, 2, 2);

        GridPane.setConstraints(healthLabel, 2, 0);
        GridPane.setValignment(healthLabel, VPos.TOP);

        GridPane.setConstraints(healthDisplay, 3, 0);
        GridPane.setValignment(healthDisplay, VPos.TOP);

        GridPane.setConstraints(manaLabel, 2, 1);
        GridPane.setValignment(manaLabel, VPos.TOP);

        GridPane.setConstraints(manaDisplay, 3, 1);
        GridPane.setValignment(manaDisplay, VPos.TOP);

        listView = new ListView<>();
        listView.getItems().addAll("Action 1", "Action 2", "Action 3", "Action 4");
        listView.setPrefWidth(260);
        listView.setMaxWidth(260);
        listView.setPrefHeight(150);
        GridPane.setConstraints(listView, 0, 2, 1, 1);

        actionDescArea.setPrefWidth(100);
        actionDescArea.setPrefHeight(150);
        actionDescArea.setWrapText(true);
        actionDescArea.setEditable(false);
        GridPane.setConstraints(actionDescArea, 1, 2, 1, 1);
        GridPane.setHgrow(actionDescArea, Priority.ALWAYS);

        actionBtn.setPrefWidth(260);
        actionBtn.setPrefHeight(60);
        GridPane.setConstraints(actionBtn, 0, 3);

        grid.getChildren().addAll(descArea, healthLabel, healthDisplay, manaLabel, manaDisplay, listView, actionBtn, actionDescArea);

        Scene scene = new Scene(grid, 950, 750);
        window.setScene(scene);
        window.show();
    }
}
```

**Output :**

[image]